# Convergence of ${\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}}\left(-1\right)^{n}\frac{\cos\left(2n\right)}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis

In order to finish one big problem I'm stuck on trying to determine the convergence, indeed trying to prove that ${\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}}\left(-1\right)^{n}\frac{\cos\left(2n\right)}{n}$ is convergent. Any ideas? Thank you in advance! Is the $(-1)^{n}$ necessary?

Comment: Dirichlet's test.

Comment: $\cos{z}={e^{iz}+e^{-iz}\over2}$

Comment: @zhw. Does it matter for this convergence in particular if it's ${\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}}\left(-1\right)^{n}\frac{\cos\left(2n\right)}{n}$ or ${\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}}\frac{\cos\left(2n\right)}{n}$

Comment: It doesn't matter as $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^k\cos (2k) = \text {Re } e^{i(2+\pi)}\frac{e^{i(2+\pi)n}-1}{e^{i(2+\pi)}-1}$$ and this remains bounded.